# Deleting dynamically created button

Tags: javascript, html

I am making an English to hindi transliteration webpage that works offline. I have used HTML & javascript so the file works on all browsers across all OS.

I have added support for remembering words used via a cookie provided the user works on same computer, same browser every time.

As the user types word , buttons are dynamically created which suggest on basis of database stored in cookie. Is there a way I can associate action on right clicking a dynamically created button ?

Also , I want that - the dynamically created button should vanish on right clicking it ?
I want this because , if user wants to remove an erroneous entry from his vocab database (which is in a cookie referred above).

Currently I am able to remove all dynamic buttons in one go using

```
id-of-span-which-holds-dynamic-buttons.innerHTML = '';
```

A lengthier way would be to remove all buttons , then pop out word from database & recreate suggestion based on current database. Is there a simpler way ?

Where can I post my web page code (**>51KB**) if somebody wants to see what I have been talking about?

Comment: In order to make use of paragraphs on stackoverflow leave one blank line. In order to move the cursor to the next line use this keyboard button: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Enter.png

Comment: @Tiberiu-IonuțStan - awesome

Answer (score 1):

> I have added support for remembering words used via a cookie

This is a really bad idea. It incurs a big overhead in every HTTP request - and eventually it will get to apoint where the requests get too large foer the server to cope with - then bad things can start happenning. HTML5 has proper support for local storage. Use it.

> Is there a way I can associate action on right clicking a dynamically created button

Have a look around the web - do you see anything similar implemented anywhere? I never have. Trying to take over the right mouse button is a bad idea.

Comment: as told before , the web page does not need any network to function so cookie is stored on local computer & processed there itself , never sent to any external device.

Comment: Okay , it seems that one cannot associate any right click action to a button . Can you tell me a method to remove dynamically created single child element ?

Comment: infanticide , suicide sounds humour+wise . Also , 'root has no parent' is a great observation.

I cannot understand
element = document.getElementById("element-id");
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
Can you tell me a way in which I can dynamically create a button which deleted itself on being pressed ?

Comment: hi guys , can you suggest me an html element which i can create dynamically . It should have atleast 2 parts - one will so append text to user-text-box while clicking on other should delete the element itself from webpage ?

Please suggest.